# take more time filter from 230 million records in hive table compare to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive, tez

I am working with `hive` table to execute one of sql to fetch some records from 230 million records but it is taking 300 seconds to execute with map reduce process and `mysql` fetches this information in less 1 seconds. Why `hive` take more time?

I am using `Ambari` Cluster with `Tez` engine. I am confused for moving database on `hadoop`.

Comment: We can't really "guide you" and we don't really have concerns, that's something you might have.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous reasons why MySQL might perform better than Hive on a *particular* query.  In that sense, your query is too broad.

The most likely cause are indexes in MySQL.  If you have a lot of data, MySQL can optimize queries using indexes.  Hive reads all the data and processes it.  MySQL can optimize the data being processed.

There are other causes as well.  If the data is stored in partitions, perhaps MySQL does a better job of partition pruning based on the `where` clause.

Without knowing the data and the query, there is no generalization.  For a single query, this is not too surprising.  In general, Hive is going to be faster on queries that need to process large amounts of data.